# Looking for a better performance on PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to build a model in PySpark and I'm obviously doing many wrong things.

What I have to do:

I have a list of products, and I have to compare each product to a corpus that will return the most similar ones, and then I have to filter by the product's type.

Here is an example with one product:

- 1st step:

```
    product_id = 'HZM-1914'
    type = get_type(product_id) #takes 8s. I'll show this function below
    similar_list = [(product_id , 1.0)] + model.wv.most_similar(positive=id_produto, topn=5) #takes 0.04s
    #the similar list shows the product_id and the similarity, it looks like this:
    [('HZM-1914', 1.0), ('COL-8430', 0.9951900243759155), ('D23-2178', 0.9946870803833008), ('J96-0611', 0.9943861365318298), ('COL-7719', 0.9930003881454468), ('HZM-1912', 0.9926838874816895)]
```

- 2nd step:

```
#I want to filter the types, so I transform the list in a dataframe, and here is what is taking the longest to perform (and probably what is wrong)
rdd = sc.parallelize([(id, get_type(id), similarity) for (id, similarity) in similar_list]) #takes 55s
products = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=str(x[0]), type=str(x[1]), similarity=float(x[2]))) #takes 0.02s
df_recs = sqlContext.createDataFrame(products) #takes 0.02s
df_recs.show() #takes 0.43s
+--------+----------------+------------------+
|    name|            type|      similarity  |
+--------+----------------+------------------+
|HZM-1914|       Chuteiras|               1.0|
|COL-8430|       Chuteiras|0.9951900243759155|
|D23-2178|           Bolas|0.9946870803833008|
|J96-0611|Luvas de Goleiro|0.9943861365318298|
|COL-7719|           Bolas|0.9930003881454468|
|HZM-1912|       Chuteiras|0.9926838874816895|
+--------+----------------+------------------+
```

- 3rd step:

```
#Comes the filter:
df_recs = df_recs.filter(df_recs.type == type) #takes 0.09s
df_recs.show() #takes 0.5s
+--------+---------+------------------+
|    name|     type|      similarity  |
+--------+---------+------------------+
|HZM-1914|Chuteiras|               1.0|
|COL-8430|Chuteiras|0.9951900243759155|
|HZM-1912|Chuteiras|0.9926838874816895|
+--------+---------+------------------+
```

- The get_type() function is:

```
def get_type(product_id):
    return df.filter(col("ID") == product_id).select("TYPE").collect()[0]["TYPE"]
```

And the DataFrame that get_type() gets ID and type is:

```
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|ID        |        NAME        |           TYPE     |
+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    7983  |SNEAKERS 01         |            Sneakers|
|    7034  |SHIRT 13            |               Shirt|
|    3360  |SHORTS 15           |               Short|
```

The get_type() function and creating the dataframe are the main issues. So if you have any idea how to make it work better, it would be really helpful. I come from Python and I'm struggling a lot with PySpark. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The fact that you're calling `.collect()` is going to take the longest time. Also not clear where `df` comes from

Comment: @OneCricketeer you mean on the get_type() function? Should I just remove the .collect()? 
I'll edit the question with the df

Comment: `.collect()[0]` is the same as `head(1)`, or limit, or similar function, but it doesn't need to collect the entire dataframe into memory first, which is what would take the most time